# May I stay a further 90 days in France after my student visa ends?

Tags: visas, france, brazilian-citizens

I am a Brazilian who has a student visa for 1 year. Brazilians are allowed to stay in France for 90 days without a visa. So, may I stay in France for 90 days after the expiration date of my visa? I don't know if 90 days is included in the visa.